# Python - Django - Heavy lifting in C++

Tags: c++, django, parallel-processing, architecture, distributed-computing

Currently i have to deal with a architectural problem.

My task is to solve some big image processing issues and somehow expose the evaluated data, e.g. as json.

So what i thought of:

1. Create a application which does the heavy lifting(image processing, c++) and return its evaluated data in json format
2. Create a webapp(e.g. Django) which calls this c++ app and exposes the returned data in json as well. This webapp would kind of act as a gateway to the world(www).

In the next step anybody could access the webapp and display the data according to rest api defined in the webapp.

What do you think of it in general? Do you know better ways to solve this kind of problems? What are your preferred architectures?

Thanks and Greetings!

Comment: Just going to put this out their: OpenCV has bindings for python, which is what I usually used for image processing. Also there is a python implementation that JIT’s the code at launch.

Comment: I'd implement everything in Python first, then profile to find the performance problem areas.  Then try to improve those problem area, still in Python.  Then figure out how to some performance improvement libraries (e.g., NumPy or OpenCV) in Python.  Then, if performance isn't performant enough, write the critical parts in C++.  Then profile the C++ (which you'll probably discover the C++ isn't any faster or slower than the Python).  Then start using threads and SIMD intrinsics.  Profiling at every step along the way.